# For Http and Name Value Pair depricated issues i have downgraded from sdk compile version23 to sdk 21 and i was having an error

Tags: android

I was new to android development anyone help we with this error

When i have changed my compile version and build tool version i have solved with depreciated issue and got an error message and build was failed.

Error message i have got is:-

> C:\Users\Muralivss\AndroidStudioProjects\Imagetest\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-hdpi\abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png:
>   libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
>   edited
>       C:\Users\Muralivss\AndroidStudioProjects\Imagetest\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-xhdpi\abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png:
>   libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
>   edited
>       C:\Users\Muralivss\AndroidStudioProjects\Imagetest\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-hdpi\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png:
>   libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
>   edited
>       C:\Users\Muralivss\AndroidStudioProjects\Imagetest\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-xhdpi\abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png:
>   libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
>   edited
>       C:\Users\Muralivss\AndroidStudioProjects\Imagetest\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-mdpi\abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png:
>   libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
>   edited
>       C:\Users\Muralivss\AndroidStudioProjects\Imagetest\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-hdpi\abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png:
>   libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
>   edited
>       :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:processDebugResources
>       C:\Users\Muralivss\AndroidStudioProjects\Imagetest\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
>       Error:(13, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
>       C:\Users\Muralivss\AndroidStudioProjects\Imagetest\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml
>       Error:(5, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Users\Muralivss\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 1
> >         Information:BUILD FAILED

This is my gradle page:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.muralivss.imagetest"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies{

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
//compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1
//compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'

}
```

This is my styles.xml file:-

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: When you get a warning that something is deprecated, the logical thing to do is update your code to the new standard or whatever took the place of the old code, not roll back to an older version cause soon you might see yourself building for Froyo again. I'd suggest you try to build towards the latest APIs and adjust your code to be runnable by older devices as well. Of course, if you were an advanced developer and already had hundreds of lines of code already done, then that's not 100% true but still...

Comment: as i was a beginner i was unable to use NameValuePair in the sdk 23 so how can i solve this. while i am searching for the solutions they suggest for the downgrade only. please provide if there is alternate way

Comment: Unrelated: Keep your support library versions consistent. You can't just pair recyclerview-v7-22.0.0 with design-23.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

1) Go back to compile api 23, back to support libraries 23.1.1, back to build tools 23.0.2.

2) Add this to your module's build.gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Comment: ya it worked for me but it was showing strikes on the http requsts

Comment: @Murali See http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html Apache HTTP Client Removal